# Getting a very simple stablebaselines3 example to work

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I tried to  model the simplest coin flipping game where you have to predict if it is going to be a head.  Sadly it won't run, given me:

```
Using cpu device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/python/simplegame.py", line 40, in <module>
    model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)
  File "/home/user/python/mypython3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py", line 315, in learn
    return super().learn(
  File "/home/user/python/mypython3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py", line 264, in learn
    total_timesteps, callback = self._setup_learn(
  File "/home/user/python/mypython3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py", line 423, in _setup_learn
    self._last_obs = self.env.reset()  # type: ignore[assignment]
  File "/home/user/python/mypython3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py", line 77, in reset
    obs, self.reset_infos[env_idx] = self.envs[env_idx].reset(seed=self._seeds[env_idx], **maybe_options)
TypeError: CoinFlipEnv.reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed'
```

Here is the code:

```
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

class CoinFlipEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, heads_probability=0.8):
        super(CoinFlipEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(2)  # 0 for heads, 1 for tails
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(2)  # 0 for heads, 1 for tails
        self.heads_probability = heads_probability
        self.flip_result = None

    def reset(self):
        # Reset the environment
        self.flip_result = None
        return self._get_observation()

    def step(self, action):
        # Perform the action (0 for heads, 1 for tails)
        self.flip_result = int(np.random.rand() < self.heads_probability)

        # Compute the reward (1 for correct prediction, -1 for incorrect)
        reward = 1 if self.flip_result == action else -1

        # Return the observation, reward, done, and info
        return self._get_observation(), reward, True, {}

    def _get_observation(self):
        # Return the current coin flip result
        return self.flip_result

# Create the environment with heads probability of 0.8
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: CoinFlipEnv(heads_probability=0.8)])

# Create the PPO model
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)

# Train the model
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

# Save the model
model.save("coin_flip_model")

# Evaluate the model
obs = env.reset()
for _ in range(10):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    print(f"Action: {action}, Observation: {obs}, Reward: {rewards}")
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is in version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gymnasium.Env`](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/#gymnasium.Env.reset) class has the following signature which divers from the one by `DummyVecEnv` which takes no arguments.

`Env.reset(self, *, seed: int | None = None, options: dict[str, Any] | None = None) → tuple[ObsType, dict[str, Any]]`

in other words `seed` and `options` are keyword-only which your own `reset` function needs to implement. It returns the `observation, info` tuple in the end.

The problems to note:

- Signature of `reset` does not match, needs `seed` and `options`
- Return signature of `reset` does not match. It needs to return a **valid observation (ObsType) and a dictionary**
- Return signature of `step` does not match, needs to say if result is truncated / model went out of bounds. (see below)

```
 def reset(self, *, seed=None, options=None): # Fix input signature
        # Reset the environment
        self.flip_result = 0 # None is not a valid Observation
        return self.flip_result, {} # Fix return signature
```

If you return None, as underlying numpy arrays are used `array([0])[0]=obs <- None` would throw another error.

---

`step` needs to have five returns parameters `observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info`

```
    def step(self, action):
        # Perform the action (0 for heads, 1 for tails)
        self.flip_result = int(np.random.rand() < self.heads_probability)

        # Compute the reward (1 for correct prediction, -1 for incorrect)
        reward = 1 if self.flip_result == action else -1

        # Return the observation, reward, done, truncated, and info
        return self._get_observation(), reward, True, False, {}
```

---

Now the models trains:

```
-----------------------------
| time/              |      |
|    fps             | 5608 |
|    iterations      | 1    |
|    time_elapsed    | 0    |
|    total_timesteps | 2048 |
-----------------------------
-----------------------------------------
| time/                   |             |
|    fps                  | 3530        |
|    iterations           | 2           |
|    time_elapsed         | 1           |
|    total_timesteps      | 4096        |
| train/                  |             |
|    approx_kl            | 0.020679139 |
|    clip_fraction        | 0.617       |
|    clip_range           | 0.2         |
|    entropy_loss         | -0.675      |
|    explained_variance   | 0           |
|    learning_rate        | 0.0003      |
|    loss                 | 0.38        |
|    n_updates            | 10          |
|    policy_gradient_loss | -0.107      |
|    value_loss           | 1           |
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
| time/                   |             |
|    fps                  | 3146        |
|    iterations           | 3           |
|    time_elapsed         | 1           |
|    total_timesteps      | 6144        |
| train/                  |             |
|    approx_kl            | 0.032571375 |
|    clip_fraction        | 0.628       |
|    clip_range           | 0.2         |
|    entropy_loss         | -0.599      |
|    explained_variance   | 0           |
|    learning_rate        | 0.0003      |
|    loss                 | 0.392       |
|    n_updates            | 20          |
|    policy_gradient_loss | -0.104      |
|    value_loss           | 0.987       |
-----------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
| time/                   |           |
|    fps                  | 2984      |
|    iterations           | 4         |
|    time_elapsed         | 2         |
|    total_timesteps      | 8192      |
| train/                  |           |
|    approx_kl            | 0.0691616 |
|    clip_fraction        | 0.535     |
|    clip_range           | 0.2       |
|    entropy_loss         | -0.417    |
|    explained_variance   | 0         |
|    learning_rate        | 0.0003    |
|    loss                 | 0.335     |
|    n_updates            | 30        |
|    policy_gradient_loss | -0.09     |
|    value_loss           | 0.941     |
---------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
| time/                   |            |
|    fps                  | 2898       |
|    iterations           | 5          |
|    time_elapsed         | 3          |
|    total_timesteps      | 10240      |
| train/                  |            |
|    approx_kl            | 0.12130852 |
|    clip_fraction        | 0.125      |
|    clip_range           | 0.2        |
|    entropy_loss         | -0.189     |
|    explained_variance   | 0          |
|    learning_rate        | 0.0003     |
|    loss                 | 0.536      |
|    n_updates            | 40         |
|    policy_gradient_loss | -0.0397    |
|    value_loss           | 0.806      |
----------------------------------------
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [-1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [-1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [-1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [-1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [1.]
Action: [1], Observation: [0], Reward: [1.]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your class CoinFlipEnv does not conform to the gym.Env interface, specifically the reset function.  According to the documentation available here https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/#gymnasium.Env.reset the reset function takes a seed parameter so your function:

`def reset(self)`

Must also take one like so(it also says it takes an options keyword argument as well so lets include that too):

`def reset(self, seed=None, options=None)`

That it what the last line of the stacktrace is telling you when it says:

`obs, self.reset_infos[env_idx] = self.envs[env_idx].reset(seed=self._seeds[env_idx], **maybe_options)`

The object self.envs[env_idx] is an instance of your class CoinFlipEnv and it is trying to pass seed=self._seeds[env_idx] and **maybe_options to CoinFlipEnv's reset function but since it is trying to pass the named argument of seed to a function that doesn't have seed defined it raises an error.

Comment: Sadly even with that change it still doesn't run. I now get https://bpa.st/NMAQ

Comment: @Daraan I am literally running the code I pasted. Does it work for you?